# How to read cookie In jquery

Tags: c#, jquery

I have a Online Q/A web application,i want to set count down for each candidate,i want to use cookie for each candidate that store count down value,and expiry after three mints, i have wrote cookie using following code,

```
                HttpCookie candcookie = new HttpCookie("candcookie");
                Response.Cookies["candcookie"]["RollNumber"] = cnic;
                Response.Cookies["candcookie"]["time"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
                candcookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(3);
                Response.Cookies.Add(candcookie);
```

i want a jquery code to read this code and display a counter,and after finishing time durtion,redirect user to Result.aspx page,
the reason of using cookie because simple jquery count down reset on page refresh.

Answer (score 1):

you can read cookies wiht jquery cookie

```
 <script src="path/to/jquery.js"></script>
     <script src="path/to/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
```

and read cookies with

```
    $.cookie("name");
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the cookie value use `$.cookie("cookiename");` and to set the cookie use `$.cookie("cookiename", value);` and to remove the cookie use `$.removeCookie("cookiename");`